# Filter and map over updated array and render in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sandbox for the example below can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kmmm0l2mmv).

I have a table of schedules that can be marked for export via a slider.
If a schedule is marked for export the below function will update an array with the value of `id`. So for example if two schedules were marked for export the updated array would look like this: `["704", "1403"]`.

The values from the updated array are then mirrored in a different table that shows they are indeed marked for export. If you look at the sandbox, it's only rendering the `id`, but I want all the values from each schedule to be rendered in the export table.

```
  slider = ({ id, startTime, selfUri, status, isExported }) => {
    if (isExported === true) {
      this.setState(
        {
          scheduleIdsToExport: [id, ...this.state.scheduleIdsToExport],
          startTime,
          selfUri,
          status
        },
        () => console.log(this.state.scheduleIdsToExport)
      );
    } else {
      const newArray = this.state.scheduleIdsToExport.filter(
        storedId => storedId !== id,
        storedSelfUri => storedSelfUri !== selfUri
      );
      this.setState(
        {
          scheduleIdsToExport: newArray
        },
        () => console.log(this.state.scheduleIdsToExport)
      );
    }
  };
```

I'm mapping over the updated array `schedulesIdsToExport` to render in the export table like this:

```
<Table.Body>
  {Object.keys(scheduleIdsToExport)
    .filter(id => id !== undefined)
    .map(id => {
      return (
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>{scheduleIdsToExport[id]}</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      );
    })}
</Table.Body>
```

I want to keep the array `scheduleIdsToExport` in tact, but also have an array `schedulesToExport` that has all the schedules and its values so I can use that in rendering the export table.

So do I need to add all the keys of `schedules` to the `.map()`? I've tried a few different arrangements and gotten weird outcomes.

**EDIT: Changes to the slider function, still having trouble with render**

```
  slider = ({ id, startTime, selfUri, status, isExported }) => {
    if (isExported === true) {
      this.setState(
        {
          scheduleIdsToExport: [id, ...this.state.scheduleIdsToExport],
          schedulesToExport: [
            id,
            status,
            selfUri,
            startTime,
            ...this.state.schedulesToExport
          ]
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.scheduleIdsToExport);
          console.log(this.state.schedulesToExport);
        }
      ); ...
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why dont you do it like this?

```
<Table.Body>
  {schedules
    .filter(schedule => scheduleIdsToExport.includes(schedule.id))
    .map(item => {
         return (
           <Table.Row>
              <Table.Cell>{item.id}</Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>{item.startTime}</Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>{item.selfUri}</Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>{item.status}</Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>
         );
     })}
</Table.Body>
```

Comment: it seems that you are missing key for Table.Row